# Bash script sourcing config file but can't use vars in arithmetic

Tags: bash, math, config

This is killing me. I have a config file, "myconfig.cfg", with the following content:

```
SOME_VAR=2
echo "I LOVE THIS"
```

Then I have a script that I'm trying to run, that sources the config file in order to use the settings in there as variables. I can print them out fine, but when I try to put one into a numeric variable for use in something like a "seq  " command, I get this weird "invalid arithmetic operator" error. 
Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./myconfig.cfg
echo "SOME_VAR=${SOME_VAR}"
let someVarNum=${SOME_VAR}
echo "someVarNum=${someVarNum}"
```

And here's the output:

```
I LOVE THIS
SOME_VAR=2
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
someVarNum=
```

I've tried countless things that theoretically shouldn't make a difference, and, surprise, they don't. I simply can't figure it out. If I simply take the line "SOME_VAR=2" and put it directly into the script, everything's fine. I'm guessing I'll have to read in the config file line by line, split the strings by "=", and find+create the variables I want to use manually.

Comment: It's completely unnecessary to swear in your question. Please [edit] to remove the bad language. While you're about it, code snippets are only for HTML/JS/CSS, so you should just use normal code blocks for shell scripts and console output.

Comment: By the way, I have a feeling that your error messages may be a result of incorrect line endings. Are you running a script that you wrote on Windows on a Linux system, or something like that?

Comment: I'm an adult, so I don't believe in things like unicorns or evil combinations of letters that shouldn't be read. But lucky for you, ranger rick took it upon himself to edit it for the less evolved.

Comment: Which two lines are out of order? The config file gets sourced, printing "I LOVE THIS" (yay), then the "echo SOME_VAR=..." line gets run, printing that SOME_VAR is 2, as it should be. Then the "let..." line runs, generating the error output, then the final "echo someVarNum..." line runs, and shows that someVarNum has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is precisely as indicated in a comment by @TomFenech. The first line (and possibly all the lines) in `myconfig.cfg` is terminated with a Windows CR-LF line ending. Bash considers CR to be an ordinary character (not whitespace), so it will set `SOME_VAR` to the two character string <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd>. (CR is the character with hex code 0x0D. You could see that if you display the file with a hex-dumper: `hd myconfig.cfg`.)

The `let` command performs arithmetic on numbers. It also considers the CR to be an ordinary character, but it is neither a digit nor an operator so it complains. Unfortunately, it does not make any attempt to sanitize the display of the character in the error message, so the carriage return is displayed between the two `"` symbols. Consequently, the end of the error message overwrites the beginning.

Don't create Unix files with a Windows text editor. Or use a utility like `dos2unix` to fix them once you copy them to the Unix machine.

Comment: This was it. I had actually spent some time looking into this as one of the first (of many) things I found might be the problem, but doing a search in my editor (sublime text), for "\r" (with regex enabled) showed no results. Using "\n" did, so I assumed I was doing the search correctly, but perhaps "\r" is the wrong code or whatever it's called... I do think I just saw that one place and assumed it was correct without looking for any verification.

Comment: But yeah, ran dos2unix on the file and it fixed it. Is there a way I can set sublime text to only use linefeeds? Don't worry about it, I'm sure that info is available somewhere. I'm running Windows with a Linux VM, and I just prefer using tools like text editors and IDEs in Windows if I can for various reasons. It's actually never been an issue until switching to using SourceTree for accessing the Git repo instead of TortoiseGit... it was a problem with all files originally but I thought I fixed it (don't know how off the top of my head), but maybe not completely, or maybe this is unrelated.